# Как писать комментарии к параметрам метода?

Tags: c#, документация, комментарии

В каком виде следует писать комментарии к параметрам метода, чтобы при вызове метода в его подсказке были эти комментарии?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть такая штука - xml-комментарии. Они отличаются от обычных тем, что предваряются тремя слэшами, а не двумя. Например:

```
/// <summary>
/// Описание метода
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg">Описание параметра</param>
/// <returns>Ogbcfybt возвращаемого значения</returns>
public int SomeMethod(string arg)
```

Answer (score 7):

Ставите /// слеша перед именем члена, далее студия сгенерирует вам заглушку для комментариев. Заполнить ее можно как в примере.

```
/// <summary>
/// Некоторый метод.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="count">Количество</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public void Method(int count)
{

}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, что не правильно задал тему вопроса.
Я писал с мобильника, в нем есть функция подставлять слова. Я не заметил, что он исправил мне слово. А как сейчас исправить, я не знаю